Display is a bit higher than normal
The first thing that i noticed after installing Ubuntu is how there always seems to be a small black bar at the bottom of my screen and everything a bit elevated, see what I mean by comparing the:
Ubuntu display

and Windows display

(See the bottom and upper portion of the displays' images). The upper portion of the Ubuntu display just feels a bit off with it's date and time too close to the monitor borders, I've used the built-in auto scaling option from the monitor and all it did was adjust the display horizontally, and did not remove the black bar at the bottom of the screen. Help is much appreciated.
This is what I got after running xrandr in the terminal:
    Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1368 x 768, maximum 16384 x 16384
    VGA-0 connected primary 1368x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
       1024x768      60.00 +
       1600x900      59.82  
       1400x900      59.88  
       1368x768      59.88*   59.85  
       1280x800      59.91    59.81  
       1280x720      59.86    59.74  
       1024x576      59.90    59.82  
       960x540       59.82    59.63  
       864x486       59.92    59.57  
       800x600       72.19    60.32    56.25  
       800x450       59.82  
       700x450       59.88  
       684x384       59.88    59.85  
       640x480       59.94  
       640x400       59.98    59.88  
       640x360       59.86    59.83  
       512x384       60.00  
       512x288       60.00    59.92  
       480x270       59.82    59.63  
       432x243       59.92    59.57  
       400x300       72.19  
       320x240       60.05  
    DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    None-1-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
       1024x768      60.00 +

Specs:
GPU: Nvidia GTX 650
Monitor: AOC E970SWN in 1366×768 (although it shows 1368x768 in Ubuntu after running xrandr) for both images

Can you update your original question with the full results of running xrandr in a terminal. Use the Code Sample formatting option above the question edit box to ensure it shows correctly in your question.

I've added the results of running xrandr

Hi, I edited my answer below.

Have you done the monitor auto adjust?
EDIT ANSWER SINCE SUBSEQUENT INFO FROM OP:
I think the difference in resolution from your monitors native 1366×768 resolution to Ubuntu's actual 1368x768 resolution is due to VESA or driver standards that VGA resolutions must be mod 8 (divisible by 8).
That could be the reason that the image is not shown quite right even after doing a monitor auto-adjust.
The only suggestion I can make now is to try changing to a different custom resolution, either one that may be listed in Ubuntu already such as 1024x768 or you could try adding a custom resolution of something like 1360x768 to see if that gets you a better image alignment.
See here for details on using cvt to generate a modeline (e.g. cvt 1360 768 60, then 2 or 3 xrandr commands to create a new mode, add it and set the VGA output.

Although didn't remove the black bar, still the most helpful answer I've gotten even when compared to scrolling the internet, thanks man.

I've managed to remove the black bar completely by setting a custom resolution and running a few auto monitor adjusts, thanks man.
